# Can't detect gestures inside an iframe using ionic on-touch or $ionicGesture?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an iframe in my ionic app. How can I detect gestures inside the iframe? I can detect gestures on the borders of content that contains the iframe using

```
<ion-content scroll="true" overflow-scroll="true" on-touch="onTouch()"></ion-content>
```

but I can't detect gestures such as tap on the elements inside the iframe! Also tried

```
<iframe ng-src={{iframeSrc}} height="600px" width="320px" frameborder="0" margin: 0 auto; display: block; overflow:hidden;" scrolling="no" on-touch="onTouch()"></iframe>
```

I have also tried $ionicGesture to access the elements in the iframe like

```
var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#iframe')); 
$ionicGesture.on('tap', function(e){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      alert('Tap');
    })    
  }, element);
```

In the pen below you can see that tapping on the red area works find but tapping on the iframe you don't get any response.

https://codepen.io/rdiamond/pen/oLEgNy

but it doesn't work! Any idea?